# Use Scifinder API calls to get properties data like density and boiling point

Tags: python, database

My supervisor bought scifinder API, and I tried the Python example they provided in the "CAS Workflow API Introduction" document.

However, the document only gives the example of searching for "casRn" "uri" etc with its code, but I want to know how to access more properties like density ,boiling point, critical temperature, molecular weight as well as reaction search, etc.

(The following code is from their document. I’m not good at Python, I found there’s no density or boiling point in variable `json`. I think to get more data except `casRn` and `uri` I should change the URL string in `request.get()` or something else. So can you tell me what should I change in the code if I want to get those properties I need.)

```
import requests
Bearer_Token=<token>
search = "50000"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(Bearer_Token)}
resp = requests.get('https://helium.cas.org/integration/v1/substances?str=Cc1nc%28n%28n1%29C%28C%29C%29c2cn3c%28n2%29-c4ccc%28cc4OCC3%29c5cnn%28c5%29C%28C%29%28C%29C%28%3DO%29N&strMode=drw&offset=0&length=100&echo=false&strHighlight=false&facet=true&fq=Number%20of%20Components%3A1',headers=headers)
if resp.status_code != 200:
 # This means something went wrong.
 raise Exception('GET substances/ {}'.format(resp.status_code))
json = resp.json()
for substance in json['substances']:
 print('{} {} {}'.format(substance['casRn'], substance['uri'], substance['name']))

resp = requests.get('https://helium.cas.org/integration/v1/substances?str=Cc1nc%28n%28n1%29C%28C%29C%29c2cn3c%28n2%29-c4ccc%28cc4OCC3%29c5cnn%28c5%29C%28C%29%28C%29C%28%3DO%29N&strMode=drw&offset=0&length=100&echo=false&strHighlight=false&facet=true&fq=Number%20of%20Components%3A1',headers=headers)
json = resp.json()
for substance in json['substances']:
 print('{} {} {}'.format(substance['casRn'], substance['uri'], substance['name']))
```

I tried to change the URL but get error, and I print the whole json, but didn't find that data.  However, the document  says it has boiling points etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways to pass parameters for your request. The first is to add them to the link of your request via '&', for example

**&your_parameter=your_value**

But this is not the best way to pass parameters, use the accepted method from the library https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Make dictionary

```
params = {'str': 'str=Cc1nc%28n%28n1%29C%28C%29C%29c2cn3c%28n2%29-c4ccc%28cc4OCC3%29c5cnn%28c5%29C%28C%29%28C%29C%28%3DO%29N', 'str_mode': 'drw', 'offset': 0, 'your_parameter': 'your_value'}
```

And send request

```
    resp = requests.get('https://helium.cas.org/integration/v1/substances',headers=headers, params=params)

json = resp.json()
```

You can find the list of necessary parameters for endpoint in the documentation of your service. If the added parameters from the documentation of your service do not work, there are most likely problems on the server side.